# Increase CSS atribute on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if there is a way to increase the value of a css attribute when a button is clicked.

For example the css would be

```
.Testclass{
font-size:30px;
}
```

is there a way to increase the number in that css attribute by 10 every time the button is click either suing js or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below...

**EDIT (see comments below):**
Put this into the function

```
 var p = parent_window.document.body;
 var size = $('#teleprompter',p).css('font-size').slice(0,-2);
 size-=10;
 $('#teleprompter',p).css('font-size',size+'px');
```

**Other snippet (old):**

```js
$('button[name=btn]').click(function(){
  var size = $('.Testclass').css('font-size').slice(0,-2);
  size -=10;
  $('.Testclass').css('font-size',size+'px')
  });
```

```css
.Testclass{
font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="btn">Make the font-size smaller!</button><div class="Testclass">TEXT</div>
```

Greetings from Austria

Comment: would it matter if the actual css is in a separate file?

Comment: Oh i believe this could be a problem...

Comment: is there a work around for that

Comment: So i've tried it with an external CSS and it also works... show me your code (html + jscript)

Comment: can i link you to a zip of my code?

Comment: Okay just post it here

Comment: here is my code - to run it use internet explorer - http://www.mediafire.com/download/nij4052lrb4f6xg/app.zip

Comment: the button to change the size is in the popup

Comment: So when i open it both buttons work? And you can try to work with `$('#teleprompter',window.parent.document).css(...);`

Comment: Yh both buttons will works until the update text is clicked , so it would be  var size = $('.teleprompter',window.parent.document).css('font-size').slice(0,-2);

Comment: Yes! This should work

Comment: It dosent work for me

Comment: its almost like the code isnt doing anything because if i run the app in chrome and click any other button i get a security error which shows that its working

Comment: Edited the post! Should work now.

Comment: again , it still dosent work with the new code. I you see there is code there to increase and decrease text size , but that stops working after the update text button has been clicked. Is there a way to fix that>